# Returns either an object containing two values or an exception if values or not a valid range

Tags: javascript, type-safety

I have two functions, one that returns two values `min` and a `max` and another function that serves as a guard. However I would like to

1. remove the logic of the `if/else` inside the `invalidPriceRangeException` function.
2. be able to know that `priceRange` returns an a `min` and a `max` without having to know that the first number is the `min`.

Maybe I'm over complicating things?

Thanks

```
// @flow
// @format

type ExceptionError = {
  InvalidPriceRangeException: string | ExceptionInformation
}

export const priceRange = (minimumRate:number, maximumRate:number): {number, number}  => {
  this.minimumRate = minimumRate;
  this.maximumRate = maximumRate;

  // [ASK]: I would like to have this 'guard' inside the `invalidPriceRangeException` where it belongs
  if (minimumRate <= maximumRate) {
  // [ASK]: How to have priceRange return either minimumRate || maximumRate without me having to return an obj? 
    return { minimumRate, maximumRate };
  } else {
    throw new invalidPriceRangeException(minimumRate, maximumRate)
  }
};

const invalidPriceRangeException = (minimumRate:number, maximumRate:number): InvalidPriceRangeException => {
  this.minimumRate = minimumRate;
  this.maximumRate = maximumRate;

  return this.msg = `minimum (${minimumRate}) is larger than maximum (${maximumRate})`
};
```

Comment: both an implementation and requirements are strange. `priceRange` acts more like a validator. 1) why should it return `either minimumRate || maximumRate` ? 2) what is `this.minimumRate` and  `this.maximumRate` for, in function context?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest exactly I would like to extract that `validator` logic outside of the priceRange function cause it doesn't belong there. I think i have looked at it too much though.